# What's new in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, meta, news

You keep seeing little improvements here and there to the Stack Overflow engine, but apart from the Stack Overflow blog that talks of the major events I haven't heard of a blog-like site that tells you the newly implemented features. Like recently we have:

- Copy profile from Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, Meta Stack Overflow
- Comments by OP show in a box

Or can we use this question to post updates? .. with little pictures if possible.

Comment: I *do* like the OP comments highlighted. Very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general I will [post to the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) if the update is what we consider a significant one.

There are generally deployments daily with fixes and improvements of various types, but a lot of them are *extremely* tiny or even invisible (back end stuff). I don't like to bug people with that kind of unnecessary detail.

Additionally, you can get similar results using Meta-- look at **the [status-completed] tag, sorted by activity**:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=status-completed&sort=active

Granted there might be a little noise from people modifying stuff that was completed a while back, but that is not very common.

You might also want to look at **my posts in any question tagged [status-completed]**. Sometimes Jarrod or Geoff post resolutions, but it is usually me:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3a1%20%5Bstatus-completed%5D&tab=active

Comment: For those interested, would you make the subversion log available somewhere? Or is that too internal?

Comment: we do a *ton* of stuff in public, but the line has to be drawn somewhere.

Comment: Fair     enough.

Answer (score 1):

Copying across profiles has been there for a long time now.

The other thing to note is that when you flag, downvote or whatever pops up a box, it's now more in colour tune with that particular SOFU branch.

Unless you're on SuperUser, in which case you're now flapped with a flaming pink flamingo amongst all that blue.

#### 4373

Nice, the asker batting average of awarding accepted answers appears right below their mugs. Really handy for spotting the users of the system who ask and ask and ask but never bother selecting a best answer.

Comment: I kind of like the accept rate, too, but I fear it might make people accept answers that aren't really worthy of being accepted, just to keep a high percentage.

Comment: But apparently it's not showing on all questions. Exclusive of cwiki.