# Add a "what's new" feature

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats new in StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16534/whats-new-in-stackoverflow)

After reading [Greg's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34734/recent-usability-improvements) about some recent changes, and after accidentally noticing that you can click on the vote count to display the up/down totals (try it!), it occurred to me that changes to SO are often snuck in under the cover of darkness - only to be discovered by happy accident.

Could we get some kind of a "what's new" page listing recent changes? Or maybe a regular blog post with these kinds of things?

Comment: Does this count? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed+-retag-request

Comment: They are publicised - usually in an answer here on meta (just behind the "Beware of the Leopard" sign).

Comment: @Marc - that's true, but it means we all have to dig around to see changes. I'd like a list that was more clear and simple.

Comment: Plus that list doesn't sort on a 'Status Completed' date, so the relevant post might not even be on the first page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They could put a

> Site Changes

tab in the Recent page so that the envelope would light up.

Comment: Then they'd have to add tracking fields to the db to figure out when to not light the envelope.

Comment: Well, they turn off the envelope now anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The SVN number that appears below the Peak Internet logo (bottom right of the page) could be linked to a changelog that gets updated with each new published build. You wouldn't be notified of it, but if you were curious, you could check out and see what's changed.

I think, though, that Jeff and Company like to let us figure out the changes on our own. Plus, maybe they don't want the public to see their check-in comments...

Answer (score 1):

This already basically exists -- look at the [status-completed] tag, sorted by activity.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=status-completed&sort=active

Granted there might be a little noise from people modifying stuff that was completed a while back, but that is not very common.

Also you might want to look at my posts in any [status-completed] question. Sometimes Jarrod or Geoff post resolutions, but it is usually me.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3a1%20%5Bstatus-completed%5D&tab=active

Comment: Users are less likely to do that (not to mention, it's not obvious). If you better advertise your updates, more users will take advantage of them, leading to higher user satisfaction.