# Why I am getting an option to start a bounty for a question with accepted answer?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bounties

Please check screen shot below:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3gXp.png]

I am not the owner of the question and the owner has accepted an answer still when I am viewing this question **I am getting an option to start a bounty.**

I am confused:

1. Why bounty option is there when answer has been accepted?
2. Why it showing to me as I am not the owner of the question? (Is it something related to points I have? If yes then why only on this question?)

Comment: (approximate quote) ["If it's obvious, no need for a notification, people don't want to get spammed about new features." Jeff Atwood.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48087/a-better-notification-of-significant-modifications-on-the-trilogy/48238#48238) Obviously.

Comment: @gnoupi I'm not mass-spamming every user on the site for every minor new thing. It's simply never going to happen as long as I am alive. We updated the blog and the `/faq`. If you want something more than that (and keep nagging about this for months on end), may I humbly suggest there might be other websites on the internet more to your liking?

Comment: @Jeff - Ok, then, you're the boss. Just put a "status-declined" or "status-by-design" on my feature request. Won't have a reason to fight for that after. For now, I thought it was still to discuss for. But ok, no problem, won't lose more time on that.

Comment: @gnoupi I am aware of your request, I just grow weary of it being brought up at every possible opportunity.

Comment: @Jeff - don't worry, I won't bother anymore.

Comment: @Jeff: There's a difference between "mass-spamming every user on the site" and just putting a banner up on top of the homepage linking to the blog post when there are "important" changes (like this one). Besides, Gnoupis request is about "significant modifications", not "every minor new thing"!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, bounties are not attached to accepted answers anymore, and anybody with enough reputation can throw bounties to any questions older than 2 days.

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/

Comment: But i am getting this option only for this question. Not any other questions asked by some one else.

Comment: @piemesons, check questions older than 2 days, you should able to see that option.